# ssrs indicator arrows - is it possible to display in solid colour, rather than with grey shadow/gradient?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, reportbuilder3.0, reportbuilder

I want to add solid white indicator arrows into my ssrs report, but the closest I appear to be able to get is an arrow with a grey border/shadow/gradient effect, like this:

[image]

I've tried tweaking every property setting I can find to suppress this gradient effect, but no joy... Is there a way to configure these indicators to be a simple solid colour?

Alternatively, is it possible to upload my own image files into ssrs to use instead?

Appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your alternate question, Yes, you can add your own images. They can either be embedded in the report or stored in a location that the report can access. Be careful because the location the report can access locally during development is not the same as the location once it's deployed. You can use an expression to change the image name so that it is dynamic.